# WPF TextBox lostFocus event trigger

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF,
In my mainWindow I have multiple TextBox, so whenever a user enters different inputs in these textbox I want to implement those changes in the code behind, as soon as user leaves the focus of the textbox.

For example, my textBox looks like this:

```
<TextBox Name="SpiralAngleTextBox"
              Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"
              Margin="5,5,5,5" SelectedText="0"/>
```

I am not looking to do any kind of input validation. What I want is to trigger some calculations or call a function whenever the TextBox leaves focus after contents of TextBox is updated.

Comment: use Bindings. you will get the required functionality immediately

Comment: any example? all I examples that I can find use MVVM, while I am not using anything of that sort.

Comment: can you call the lostfocus event of textbox and get the contents using "TextBoxName.Text" and use the content for your purpose....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an EventHandler

```
    <TextBox Name="SpiralAngleTextBox"
      Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"
      Margin="5,5,5,5" SelectedText="0" LostFocus="SpiralAngleTextBox_LostFocus"/>
```

and in the xaml.cs

```
    private void SpiralAngleTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foo();
    }
```

If you just want it to do stuff when the textbox content changes you can try something like this:

```
            <TextBox Name="SpiralAngleTextBox"
              Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"
              Margin="5,5,5,5" SelectedText="0" LostFocus="SpiralAngleTextBox_LostFocus" 
TextChanged="SpiralAngleTextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

and in the xaml.cs

```
       bool hasChanged;

    private void SpiralAngleTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(hasChanged)
            foo();

        hasChanged = false;
    }

    private void SpiralAngleTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        hasChanged = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to bind to TextBox.Text

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty}" />
```

Where MyProperty is some property in your code-behind. This is because TextBox.Text updates on lost focus (UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus by default.) You can learn more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-control-when-the-textbox-text-updates-the-source

Comment: This is the prefered way if you follow MVVM, either that or use an EventTrigger on LostFocus with an InvokeActionCommand that binds to your View Model.  If you are not using MVVM, then you are probably creating a mess because your UI is now tightly coupled to your business logic  :-)